# python XML content control

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is a code snippet from the XML content that annotates the object tag and annotates it.

Some XML files do not have an object tag. In this case it gives a keyError error. How can I pass such xml files without giving keyError

```
annotation = read_xml(annotation_path)
image = read_image(image_path)

gt_boxes = []

for b in annotation['object']:
    try:
        label_id = self.classes.index(b['name'])
    except ValueError:
        continue

    gt_boxes.append({
        'label': label_id,
        'xmin': b['bndbox']['xmin'],
        'ymin': b['bndbox']['ymin'],
        'xmax': b['bndbox']['xmax'],
        'ymax': b['bndbox']['ymax'],
    })
```

I want to control code above `for b in annotation['object']:` command. Help me please

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
for b in annotation['object']:
```

do

```
try:
    annotation_object=annotation['object']
except KeyError:
    annotation_object=[]
    # possibly some more advanced handling for this case...
for b in annotation_object:
```